# I'm getting error while running yaml file inside minkube by command "kubectl apply -f firstpod.yaml"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

**This is my firstpod.yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
 name: webapp
spec: 
 containers: 
 - name: webappcontainer 
   image: richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0
```

**I'm getting following error:**

```
error: error validating "firstpod.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container: got "string", expected "map"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false"
```

**In OUTPUT format of  yaml file in online parser looks everything fine..you can see below to online parser output**

```
{
  "kind": "Pod", 
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "image": "richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0", 
        "name": "webappcontainer"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "apiVersion": "v1", 
  "metadata": {
    "name": "webapp"
  }
}
```

[image: yaml file in notepad++]
[image: Command where I fire command for running yaml file]

Answer (score 2):

The yaml syntax for pod should be like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  name: webapp
spec: 
  containers: 
  - name: webappcontainer 
    image: richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0
```

Comment: Can you try by copying from my answer

Comment: Yes I tried your answer also by copying but got same error. @Arghya Sadhu

Comment: For declare `image` as **map**, it should be `image: {richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular: release0}`.

Answer (score 0):

The yaml, provided by @Arghya Sadhu works like a charm and it follows all the [pod spec rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#pod-v1-core)

tested in

```
Win10
minikube version: v1.12.2 commit: be7c19d391302656d27f1f213657d925c4e1cfc2-dirty
kubectl 1.19
```

[image]

Double check if you have proper indentations while copy paste exaples, check you dont have any hidden symbols after copy-paste.
Example works everywhere - in Win+Mac minikubes, gke ans aws